# Using User Defined Function in SQL Query-MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Purchases.PONumber, SalesOrders.SalesOrderNumber, Bookings.VessalVoyage, Purchases.Quantity, Bookings.ShippingLine, Bookings.CargoCutoffDate, SalesOrders.Quantity AS Quant, SalesOrders.QuantityUOM AS QuantUOM, Bookings.BookingNumber, Shipments.FreightRate, Purchases.VendorID, Shipments.ShipmentInvoiceNumber, Shipments.InvoicePIDate, Bookings.SailingDate, Bookings.PortOfLoading, Bookings.ArrivalDate, Containers.InspectionCharge, SalesOrders.Grade, Purchases.NumberOfContainers, TruckingRates.TruckingRate, [Purchases.NumberOfContainers]*[TruckingRates.TruckingRate] AS TruckCost, IIf(IsNull([Purchases.NumberOfContainers]*[Containers.InspectionCharge]),0,[Purchases.NumberOfContainers]*[Containers.InspectionCharge]) AS Inspt, SalesOrders.SIHUID, SalesOrders.SIHUShippingAssistant, (IIf([BuyPriceUOM]='sht',[BuyPrice],IIf([BuyPriceUOM]='kg',[BuyPrice]*907.185,IIf([BuyPriceUOM]='MT',[BuyPrice]*0.907185,IIf([BuyPriceUOM]='lbs',[BuyPrice]*2000.000574,[BuyPrice]))))/IIf(Nz([BuyPriceCurrency],"USD")="USD",1,Nz([BuyPriceExchangeRate],0))) AS Buy,Query6.Load
FROM (((((Purchases INNER JOIN Containers 
ON Purchases.PONumber = Containers.PONumber) 
INNER JOIN SalesOrders 
ON Containers.SalesOrderNumber = SalesOrders.SalesOrderNumber) 
INNER JOIN Bookings 
ON Containers.BookingID = Bookings.BookingID) 
INNER JOIN Shipments 
ON Containers.ShipmentID = Shipments.ShipmentID) 
LEFT JOIN TruckingRates 
ON Containers.TruckingRateID = TruckingRates.TruckingRateID) 
LEFT JOIN Query6 
ON Containers.PONumber = Query6.PONumber
GROUP BY Purchases.PONumber, SalesOrders.SalesOrderNumber, Bookings.VessalVoyage, Purchases.Quantity, Bookings.ShippingLine, Bookings.CargoCutoffDate, SalesOrders.Quantity, SalesOrders.QuantityUOM, Bookings.BookingNumber, Shipments.FreightRate, Purchases.VendorID, Shipments.ShipmentInvoiceNumber, Shipments.InvoicePIDate, Bookings.SailingDate, Bookings.PortOfLoading, Bookings.ArrivalDate, Containers.InspectionCharge, SalesOrders.Grade, Purchases.NumberOfContainers, TruckingRates.TruckingRate, SalesOrders.SIHUID, SalesOrders.SIHUShippingAssistant, Containers.NetWeight, Purchases.BuyPrice, Purchases.BuyPriceCurrency, Purchases.BuyPriceUOM, Purchases.BuyPriceExchangeRate, Containers.WeightUOM, SalesOrders.UnitPrice, Containers.SalesOrderNumber, Containers.ContainerNo,Query6.Load;
```

In Query6 i'm using function to get "WtInMT":
Query6:

```
SELECT CInt(Round(GetWeightInMT(Sum([NetWeight]),WeightUOM),0)) AS Load, Containers.PONumber
FROM Containers
GROUP BY Containers.SalesOrderNumber, Containers.WeightUOM, Containers.PONumber;
```

Function:

```
Public Function GetWeightInMT(WtToConvert As Double, WtInUOM As String) As Double
    ' MT(Metric Tons)
    ' Pounds(lbs)      to MT: lbs / 2204.6 = MT
    ' Kilograms(kg)    to MT: kg * .001 = MT
    ' Short tons(sh t) to MT: sh t * .907185 = MT.

    Select Case WtInUOM
        Case "lbs"
            GetWeightInMT = WtToConvert / 2204.6
        Case "kg"
            GetWeightInMT = WtToConvert * 0.001
        Case "sh t"
            GetWeightInMT = WtToConvert * 0.907185
        Case Else
            GetWeightInMT = WtToConvert
    End Select
    If GetWeightInMT < 1 Then GetWeightInMT = 0

End Function
```

When I run the query I get data mismatch error.

Any Suggestions??
Thankyou

Comment: Might you be passing in `Null` as the weight anywhere? It might be worth trying `GetWeightInMT(NZ(Sum( ..`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“#type!” error on form's calculated field ms access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399668/type-error-on-forms-calculated-field-ms-access)

Comment: Seems like you forgot the answer in your previous similar question.

Comment: Thank you.I will surely try it